# Visualize chart inside for loop in flask front end

Tags: python, flask, data-visualization

The following visualization function visualizes the pairs of features given to  it. The pairs of features are dynamic, so it is kept inside for loop. This is working perfectly in the terminal output. However, Could anyone help me how to apply the same in flask ??

```
# Visualization of data
def visualization(dataframe,pair_list):
    try:
        for i in range(len(pair_list)):
                    x = pair_list[i][0]
                    y = pair_list[i][1]
                    plotdata = sns.pairplot(dataframe, x_vars = [x], y_vars = [y])
                    title = str(x) +' VS ' + str(y)
                    plotdata.fig.suptitle(title, y = 1)
                    plt.show()
    except:
        dataframe.plot()
def calling_visualization():
    visualization(dataframe_name, [(feature1, feature2), (feature3, feature4)])
    return 'visualization is done'
```

I checked the other answers that I thought might help me in stack overflow but nothing helped me. Need experts advice on the code.

Comment: You mean how to convert plot to html?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to know how to show this dynamic plt.show() inside for loop to the front end of flask webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the `fapp.py` and `index.html` from the last post.

**fapp.py:**

```
import os
import shutil

from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import Flask, session
from fastai.vision import *

from io import StringIO
import base64
import io
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import seaborn as sns

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'csv')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['csv','xls'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    response.headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=Edge,chrome=1'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return response    

def build_plot(dataframe):
    # dataframe = pd.read_csv('/home/kriti/Desktop/Iris.csv')
    pair_list = [['PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm'], ['PetalWidthCm', 'Species']]
    img = io.BytesIO()

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,5))
# 
    plotdata = []
    for i in range(2):
        x = pair_list[i][0]
        y = pair_list[i][1]
        print(x,y)
        plotdata = sns.scatterplot(data=dataframe, x=x, y=y, hue='Species', ax=axs[i])
        plt.tight_layout()
        # plotdata.legend()

    fig.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)

    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    return plot_url

    # return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(plot_url)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    # shutil.rmtree(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    # os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

    d = request.form.to_dict()
    button_name = 'None'
    if (len(d)!=0):
        button_name = list(d.items())[-1][0]

    file = request.files['file']
    print("file:",file)
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No file selected for uploading','red')
        # return redirect(request.url)
        return render_template('index.html', uploaded_csv=False)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        shutil.rmtree(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        flash('File successfully uploaded!', 'green')
        print(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
        print("==>",os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, sorted(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']))[0]))
        csv_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, sorted(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']))[0]))
        csv_shape = csv_file.shape

        disp_div = 'block'
        plot_sns = build_plot(csv_file)

        # session['csv_file'] = csv_file
        return render_template('index.html', csv_shape=csv_shape, plot_graph=plot_sns, uploaded_csv = True)
        # return redirect('/')
    else:
        flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 'red')
        # return redirect(request.url)
        return render_template('index.html',uploaded_csv=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, port=5006)

## For deploying the app use `app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)`
```

**index.html:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/index.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#target").on('submit',function(){
        // alert("It works");
    });
  });
</script>
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <form id="target" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div name ="up" class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button name="upload" class="btn">Upload CSV File</button>
        <input type="file" id="file" value="go" name="file" onchange="$('#target').submit();"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p>
       {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
         {% if messages %}
          <div class=flashes>
          {% for category_color, message in messages %}
            <p class="error_text" style="color:{{ category_color }};width:500px;">{{ message }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
         {% endif %}
       {% endwith %}
    </p>

    ===>{{ csv_shape }}

    {% if uploaded_csv %}
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_graph }}">

    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Before uploading:**
[image]

**After uploading Iris.csv file:**
[image]

You can tweak the code and write your own logic to show different plots.